# How can I deploy Couchbase server to Amazon Web Services?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, amazon-web-services, couchbase

I want to create backend form my iOS application. I have a Couchbase Lite database embedded in my iOS application and now I want to create a backend for it. I want to have a server based on Couchbase because I want to use Sync Gateway protocol to synchronize client and server instances of my databases. Are there any ways I can deploy Couchbase server to Amazon and use it as a cloud database?

Comment: Check out http://www.iriscouch.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you have a number of options to deploy a Couchbase server.  You could simply spin up an EC2 instance and install the Couchbase server yourself, tho I would recommend using a preconfigured AMI from the marketplace.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/ref=gtw_navgno_search_box?page=1&searchTerms=couchbase

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Last question - are there some way I can use it as a free trial for some time?? At this moment I don't want to use with commercial purposes - just want to try and learn for myself and after this make choice about the future production version.

Comment: Amazon AWS have a 'free tier' where you can use a micro instance for 750 hours for free, otherwise you could just start with a micro instance and simply start and stop the instance as needed. http://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_ichannel=ha&sc_ipage=what-is-cloud-computing&sc_iplace=ha_2up_slot2&sc_icampaigntype=free_tier&sc_icampaign=ha_en_freeTier/

Comment: Can you not just run Couchbase locally for development purposes?  Saves you having to launch Amazon instances and I'm pretty sure a micro version would struggle with Couchbase.

Comment: @scalabilitysolved Can you please explain in deatails what did you mean by this:" I'm pretty sure a micro version would struggle with Couchbase"??
"just run Couchbase locally for development purposes" I already did this:). The next step I want to learn and look how to work with Couchbase in the cloud - I don't have possibilities to create my own domain, so AWS looks pretty good for this.

Comment: Sorry! I was talking about the micro aws instance (free version), it probably doesn't have good enough specs to run Couchbase.

I have a post covering installing Couchbase on AWS, perhaps it'll help http://scalabilitysolved.com/installing-couchbase-on-aws/

Comment: You're right a micro would probably have a heart attack for couchbase. Only thing I can suggest is start up a bigger one and the best thing about AWS is you can play with it then stop it when you finished ya proof of concept. Only pay for what you use

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that Couchbase no longer provides Community Couchbase AMI on Amazon marketplace for new customer. Meaning you have to set it up yourself, unless you want to pay for Enterprise edition.